# Is there a video container format (mainstream or experimental) that can properly transmit Black Mirror's Bandersnatch?

Tags: video, video-conversion, video-encoding

*Black Mirror*'s [*Bandersnatch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Mirror%3A_Bandersnatch)

From Wikipedia:

> Black Mirror: Bandersnatch is a 2018 interactive film in the science fiction anthology series Black Mirror. It was written by series creator Charlie Brooker and directed by David Slade. The film premiered on Netflix on 28 December 2018, its release date only officially announced the day before. Netflix did not confirm the interactive nature of Bandersnatch until its release, though there was much media speculation.

The "interactive video" consists of approximately 150 minutes of video/audio, separated into about 250 distinct segments. After each segment is finished playing, Netflix would produce a simple menu in their interface that would allow the viewer (player?) to make a choice (I have not experienced it on Netflix, it's unclear to me how many choices, though I can't imagine you ever have more than 2 or 3). These options would be presented as phrases/sentences, and again, I assume they're fairly small (30 or 40 words, tops).

The two video containers that I believe to be the only reasonable modern choices are of course [mkv](https://www.matroska.org/index.html) and [mp4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP4_file_format). I offer these only as possibilities, perhaps someone else knows more.

I believe that multiple video/audio segments could be stuffed into either format and that these could be accessed/played with reasonably intelligent client software (VLC, ffmpeg, etc.). I also believe that a default (start segment) could be flagged so that it would be the one to play in VLC (unclear to me if other video software would honor it).

Is there a way to faithfully save/record/keep this episode? Something like DVD/Blu-ray menus might suffice.

If this isn't currently possible, is there anything on the horizon that might make it possible in the near (1-3 years) future?

Comment: see the problem here is that what you are describing is a program that contains video content, rather than a video that accepts input. just like a DVD menu is presented by a program on the DVD player that is reading standard input data off the disk, I think you are going to need to look for an executable format rather than a video one.

Comment: @FrankThomas I won't dispute this from a philsophical standpoint. My question still stands though, is there a video container that can do this? It might be the most extreme example, but DVDs and Blurays already do something like this on a smaller scale in their menu systems. A user uses a remote and selects one video to play, or another, and so on.